# Monty Hall Project

Tags: c++

I am currently in the process of writing a C++ Monty Hall Problem Simulation and have run into some trouble. The error I keep getting is:

```
source.cpp(23): error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'doorReveal' used
source.cpp(25): error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'doorSwitch' used
source.cpp(52): error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'stayWin' used
source.cpp(56): error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'switchWin' used
```

I can't seem to figure out what is wrong. The project is supposed to simulate the wins by first staying with the original door choice on the first 100 tries and then switching when door is revealed on the next 100 tries. Thank you all for your help in advance.

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <time.h>
 using namespace std;

 int main()
 {
     int doorChoice;
     int prizeDoor;
     int doorReveal;
     int doorSwitch;
     int count;
     int switchWin;
     int stayWin;

     srand((unsigned int) time(0));

     for (count = 0; count <= 200; count++)
     {
         prizeDoor = (rand() % 3) + 1;
         doorChoice = (rand() % 3) + 1;
         cout << "The prize door is door number " << prizeDoor << " ." << endl;
         cout << "The door the contestant chose was door " << doorChoice << endl;
         doorReveal != prizeDoor || doorChoice;
         cout << "The host revealed door number " << doorReveal << " ." << endl;
         doorSwitch != doorChoice || doorReveal;

         while (count < 101)
         {
             if (doorChoice == prizeDoor)
             {
                 cout << "Great Job! You won!" << endl;
             }
             else {
                 cout << "Not this time!" << endl;
             }
         }

         while (count < 201)
         {
             if (doorSwitch == prizeDoor)
             {
                 cout << "You switched and won!" << endl;
             }
             else {
                 cout << "You switched and lost!" << endl;
             }
         }

         if (doorChoice == prizeDoor)
         {
             stayWin++;
         }
         if (doorSwitch == prizeDoor)
         {
             switchWin++;
         }
         count++;
     }
     cout << "Your win percentage when staying was " << stayWin << "%!" << endl;
     cout << "Your win percentage when switching was " << switchWin << "%!" << endl;
     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Don’t declare all variables at the beginning, declare each variable where you use it first – *not earlier!* Furthermore, your variable types are wrong. You don’t want `int` for all of them.

Comment: @KonradRudolph thats really a matter of preference, its fine having them declared where they are, however they should be initialized with a default value. pptaszek you havent initialised the variables with data in some of them, check your order of operations!

Comment: @Matthew No, it isn’t. As you can see it’s error prone. It also makes the code’s logic harder to follow because it artificially bloats the program’s state. There’s a consensus that, to keep a program’s state manageable and the program readable, variables should have as small a scope as possible, and thus only be declared where they’re actually used.

Comment: @TobiasKienzler: Irrelevant. However like Konrad writes most often you don't need to waste lines and can still profit from static typing.

Comment: @BenjaminBannier Sure enough, and I fully agree with Konrad. Nonetheless if OP is relatively new to programming, starting with something easier than C++ (or rather C apart from `using namespace std` and `cout <<`) might not hurt...

Comment: Why is this question getting so many downvotes? (I've seen ***much*** worse code.)

Comment: Btw you should also be aware that the build-in rand may not be a good quality pseudo-random number generator.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Problem 1: `operator!=`

`operator !=` doesn't do what you think it does.

Did you mean

```
    doorReveal = !(prizeDoor || doorChoice);
    cout << "The host revealed door number " << doorReveal << " ." << endl;
    doorSwitch = (doorChoice || doorReveal);
```

<sub><strike>I sense another logic issue in determining the doorReveal. I'll have to think about that later.</strike></sub>***Edit: see problem 5***

#### Problem 2: `while`

There's also a problem with the while loops:

```
    while(count < 101)

    // ...

    while(count < 201)
```

They're infinite loops, because count isn't increased during the loop. I think you meant `if` there, instead of `while`.

#### Problem 3: Initiliazing `switchWin` and `stayWin`

These variables are only being incremented. Like @KonradRudolph suggested,

- declare your variables where they are first needed
- initialize them
- while you're at it, mark them `const` as appropriate

#### Problem 4: `rand()%3` is biased

You should probably use a uniform distribution.

See

- http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/arts/jsw_art_rand.aspx
- I'll leave using **[`std::uniform_int_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution)** as an exercise for the reader here, as it is likely beyond the scope of your course. **Remember  to use it** though, in any *real life* code.

#### Problem 5: Fix your door 'derivation'

Booleans aren't sets. Even if they were, you'd be stuck to *binary sets*. I propose the following model:

```
enum doors { door1 = 1, door2 = 2, door3 = 4, any = door1|door2|door3 };
```

so you can say:

```
doors const doorReveal = doors(~(prizeDoor | doorChoice)  & any);
doors const doorSwitch = doors(~(doorChoice | doorReveal) & any);
```

---

Fixing that results in a program that appears to work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

enum doors { door1 = 1, door2 = 2, door3 = 4, any = door1|door2|door3 };

static inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, doors val) {
    switch(val) {
    case door1: return os << "door #1";
    case door2: return os << "door #2";
    case door3: return os << "door #3";
    case any:   return os << "any door";
    }
    return os << "OOPS";
}

int main()
{
    unsigned switchWin = 0;
    unsigned stayWin   = 0;
    srand((unsigned int) time(0));
    for(int count = 0; count <= 200; count++)
    {
        doors const prizeDoor  = doors(1 << rand() / ( RAND_MAX / 3 ));
        doors const doorChoice = doors(1 << rand() / ( RAND_MAX / 3 )); 
        cout << "The prize door is door number " << prizeDoor << " ." << endl;
        cout << "The door the contestant chose was door " << doorChoice << endl;
        doors const doorReveal = doors(~(prizeDoor | doorChoice)  & any);
        doors const doorSwitch = doors(~(doorChoice | doorReveal) & any);

        cout << "The host revealed door number " << doorReveal << " ." << endl;
        if(count < 101)
        {
            if(doorChoice == prizeDoor)
            {
                cout << "Great Job! You won!" << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Not this time!" << endl;
            }
        };
        if(count < 201)
        {
            if(doorSwitch == prizeDoor)
            {
                cout << "You switched and won!" << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "You switched and lost!" << endl;
            }
        };
        if(doorChoice == prizeDoor)
        {
            stayWin++;
        }
        if(doorSwitch == prizeDoor)
        {
            switchWin++;
        };
        count++;
    }
    cout << "Your win percentage when staying was " << stayWin << "%!" << endl;
    cout << "Your win percentage when switching was " << switchWin << "%!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I sense another logic issue in determining the `doorReveal`. I'll have to think about that later.

Comment: 'revealed door 0' is not a valid result -- it *can't* work: `!(prizeDoor || doorChoice);` is always 0, as doors are numbered '1,2,3'. Untested, but `doorReveal = 6-prizeDoor-doorChoice` ought to work.

Comment: @Jongware Awesome. Thanks for reminding me. I decided to 'fix' it in the sane fashion: **Hold on - brainfart** Be back after lunch

Comment: @Jongware there. I think it's fixed now. There's still considerable problems with the branches (I think `<101` and `<201` should be mutually exclusive. I also think that the condition `doorChoice==prizeDoor` is being detected late.

Comment: The OP "staying with the original door choice on the first 100 tries and then switching when door is revealed on the next 100 tries .." suggests you are correct, it need to be a simple `if (count < 100) .. else ..`  The `stayWin` and `switchWin` statements can be moved inside each of these. Also: the for loop should count *up to* 200, not *including*. Your doors selection can be easier written (and mentally parsed) as `any - prizeDoor - doorChoice`, or possibly as `doorReveal = doors(any ^ prizeDoor ^ doorChoice)` (where XOR dubs for `NOT`).

Comment: @Jongware thanks for your additions. You can have a part of the rep :) I like your `^` approach, I'll remember that. I had started from the 'bit set' side. Of course, simple bit manipulation is quite clear.

Comment: @sehe I appreciate all of your help thank you and everyone else thank you for the insight on improving the readability of my code. This is for my first programming class I have ever taken and the teacher seems  very uptight on the way he wants us to write our code so I apologize if it is difficult to read. I have applied what i learned from you guys to the program and it works like a charm!